# Problem in displaying and connectivity with mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am new in php, I created a page with mysql db connectivity but when the page is run it displays a blank page. If i write a echo statement before the connection statement then only echo statement is displayed and nothing else is displayed. Here is my code..

```
  $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','admin');
mysql_select_db('testdb',$con);
if ($con) 
{
  die('Connected to database!');
}
$sql = " INSERT INTO customer ([Name],[Website]) VALUES('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]') ";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
if(!$result)
{
echo mysql_error();
exit;
}
// close the connection
mysql_free_result($result); 
mysql_close($con);
```

Anyone please help why this problem occurs and is there is anything wrong in the page.

---

Display Errors was off. I edit in the php.ini file 'display_errors' On. But still the connectivity issue is not resolved. It displays an fatal error at connectivity line statement.

```
fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()
```

Comment: what about enabling error reporting at php.ini ?

Comment: I'm assuming you're doing this locally, following one of PHP tutorials that use `mysql_*` functions which aren't bundled with php by default anymore. Try to use `mysqli_` functions and take a look at www.php.net/mysqli for details if something is unclear.

Comment: Try after giving this 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if ( ! $con)` ie youre missing `not` in the `if`?

Comment: Boy ----------- such errors are not supposed to be post on STACK -------- at least spend few hours with code and then post your problem ---- you will become good at THE ART OF DEBUGGING

Comment: @shameer: error reporting is on by default. He doesnot have any error in his script. its a logical misktake

Comment: Given the error that you are getting, you should follow @Michael J.V.'s advice and try the `mysqli_` functions (or install the PHP MySQL driver but it is tricky and hard to find the right binaries)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','admin');
    mysql_select_db('testdb',$con);
    if (!$con) 
    {
      die('Not Connected to database!');
    }
    $sql = " INSERT INTO customer ([Name],[Website]) VALUES('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]') ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
    if(!$result)
    {
    echo mysql_error();
    exit;
    }
else
{
echo 'Query Success';
}
    // close the connection
    mysql_free_result($result); 
    mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have

die('Connected to database!');

this will stop the script here, script written after it will not be executed , use instead

echo('Connected to database!');

Comment: Also replace [Name],[Website] with Name, website in your SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

**[Name],[Website]** should be replace with Name, website

Comment: also if ($con) should be if (!$con)

Comment: I think you should try doing basic things, as soon as you are getting error and you are posting on Stack --- you will not be able to learn the crucial art --- THE ART OF DEBUGGING

Answer (score 0):

your script dies everytime it success to connect to DB

change

```
if ($con) 
{
  die('Connected to database!');
}
```

to

```
if (!$con) 
{
  die('Connected to database!');
}
```